# Abrir uma janela modal para autenticação

Tags: php, javascript, modal

Possuo em meu código uma condicional `if` que quando falsa deverá abrir uma janela e solicitar a autorização de um usuário, a senha e a justificativa.

Caso não satisfaça a condicional, adicionarei uma query em uma sessão `$_SESSION['QryAuth'] = $query` para que após confirmação da senha, irei executá-la e adicionar a justificativa através de uma outra query.

Porém eu não consigo abrir a janela modal. Eu consigo abri-la automaticamente através de botões ou links. Mas queria chamá-la, dentro do **ELSE**, apenas quando não me satisfazer.

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

**PHP:**

```
...
} else {
$_SESSION['QryAuth'] = $qry; //query que deveria ser executada
echo "<script>alert(\"Cadastro Inválido. Necessária autorização!\");</script>";
//AQUI QUERIA CHAMAR A JANELA MODAL
```

**HTML:** (Janela Modal)

```
<div id="dialog" class="window">
    <a href="#" class="close">Fechar [X]</a><br />
    <h5>Necessário autorização do Supervisor!</h5>
    <br />  
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Usuário:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="usuario" name="usuario" size="20" maxlength="20"/></td>
        </tr>       
        <tr>
            <td>Senha:</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="senha" id="senha" size="20" maxlength="20"/></td>
        </tr>       
        <tr>
            <td>Justificativa:</td>
            <td><textarea name="justificativa" id="justificativa" cols="40" rows="3"/></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
    <p><input type="submit" id="enviar_auth" name="enviar_auth" value="Autorizar"/></p> 
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function open_modal( id ){
        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();

        $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

        $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);    
        $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);  

        //Get the window height and width
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();

        $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
        $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);
        $(id).fadeIn(2000); 
    };


    $(document).ready(function() {  

        $('a[name=modal]').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            open_modal( $(this).attr('href') ); 
        });

        //abrindo o div#modal ao carregar a página
        //open_modal('#dialog');

        $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $('#mask').hide();
            $('.window').hide();
        });     

        $('#mask').click(function () {
            $(this).hide();
            $('.window').hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer uma verificação no click, você precisará incluir uma chamada Ajax para a verificação no servidor:

```
$('a[name=modal]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax( {
        "verifica.php",
        success: function(data) { 
            if (data.erro) {
                alert(data.mensagem);
                open_modal(href); 
            }
        }
    });
});
```

seu código no servidor, verifica.php no caso acima, ficaria:

...
} else {
    $_SESSION['QryAuth'] = $qry; //query que deveria ser executada
    echo json_encode(array(
        'erro'=>true, 
        mensagem='Cadastro Inválido. Necessária autorização!'
    );
    exit;
}

Comment: Gustavo, incluindo `<script>open_modal('#dialog');</script>`, a janela modal também abre automaticamente. E não quero que ela esteja associada ao click do botão. Pois após o clique do botão será feita uma verificação, para então abri-la.

Comment: Certo, não seria o caso de usar Ajax para a verificação? Editei a resposta.

Comment: Gustavo, eu fui por outro caminho (popup em JS), pois estou com urgência, mas logo testarei e darei o feedback. Obrigado.